# Browser Specific behaviors and trigger level in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser, modal-dialog

Please Guys i need assist with this project:
I am a bit confused rn, i wanted this piece of code to display a specific styled div modal designed for a specific browser. What i want is: if browser is firefox modal displays **"On My Way Home"**, styled with a class .home. else if my browser is chrome, display a modal **"Home Now"**

Thanks

$(function(){

```
function modal() {

    var options = {
        trigger: '.lp-download-btn',
        selectorClose: '.close',
        selectorContent: '#j-download-instructions',
        selectorLinks: 'a',
        chromes: '.chrome'
    };

    var $body = $(options.selectorContent);
    var $chromeBrowser = $(options.chromes);

    
    $('body').on('click', options.trigger, function() {
        $body.css({
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            visibility: 'visible'
        });
    })

    $body.on('click', function(e){
        if (this == e.target) {
            $body.hide();
            return false;
        }
    });

    $body.on('click', options.selectorClose, function(){
        $body.hide();
        return false;
    });

    $body.on('click', function() {
        $chromeBrowser.css({
            display: 'block'
        })
    })

}
function browserDetection() {
    // IE or not
    if (navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE") >=0 ){
        return modal();
    }
    

    // Chrome browser 
    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") >= 0) {
        return modal();
    }

    // Firefox Browser 
    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") >= 0) {}

    // Safari browser 
    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) {}

    // Opera browser 

    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Opera") >= 0) {}
}


browserDetection();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can perform user agent sniffing to possibly detect which browser someone is in, although it does have drawbacks https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent but in this case you can use that to do what you would like.